# Node.js canvas implementation with Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, node-canvas

To any canvas pros out there–I need help.

I'm using [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas) and I'm trying to get `imageData` using it's `getImageData` method.
Unfortunately it returns:

```
interface ImageData {
    readonly attribute unsigned long width;
    readonly attribute unsigned long height;
    readonly attribute CanvasPixelArray data;
}
```

`CanvasPixelArray` is deprecated in favor of `Uint8ClampedArray`.

My question is:

Is there a way for `getImageData` to return `Uint8ClampedArray` or to convert `CanvasPixelArray` to `Uint8ClampedArray`?

If that's not the case, maybe someone can point me to some other implementation of canvas in node?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/403

Answer (score 1):

It does just that since this [PR](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/pull/604/commits) as @ZachB has pointed out. Nowadays just <=0.10 does it the old way, as branched [here](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/607becb266a0d26c5f4a8dd1c93f4d3c29466209/src/CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc#L742) for example.